# How to delete weird folder with $ or special character created by accident?

Tags: windows-10, window

I created by accident a folder named `$..`

If I try to delete it, window say that the file don't exist.

How could I delete it?

I try to delete it parent folder, but it don't work.

Even doing `rmdir` by command line don't work.

Anyone can help my with my weird folder.

Comment: Try restarting in Safe Mode and delete it that way.  Try Lock Hunter   (lockhunter.com)

Comment: That dont work window say the folder dony exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally works.

- Open a command prompt
- Got the parent folder using cd
- type in `dir /x`.  This displays the 8.3 version of the file and foldernames.
- Look at the foldernames in the column before the full foldernames.  This will have squiggles in their names.
- Find the equivalent for `$..`
- use `rmdir` to delete that name (as it is shown)